# What's the best way to copy and insert data from related tables into a new set of related tables with Linq

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql, orm

I work on a web game , I use asp.net mvc, linqtosql.

I have 3 tables that store default game values: DefaultRegions, DefaultSubRegions and DefaultCountries. These 3 tables are related to each other thanks to primary / foreign keys.

I need to copy the values of these tables into 3 tables called Regions, SubRegions and Countries when someone creates a new Game. In these 3 tables the values for the ongoing games are saved (GameId is added to differentiate the games).

Now, I need to update the relationships, since the primary keys obviously change.

Anyone knows a way to achieve this in an efficient manner?

My idea would involve cumbersome foreach loops, maybe someone else has an idea?

**edit** looks like my initial idea is the best way to go, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, it should create and interrelate all the new auto generated ID's on submit.

```
var defaultRegions = from r in DefaultRegions
             select r;

IList<Region> rlist = new List<Region>();
foreach(var dr in defaultRegions) {
    var r = new Region {
        Name = dr.Name };

    foreach(DefaultSubRegion dsr in dr.DefaultSubRegions) {
        var sr = new SubRegion {
            Name = dsr.Name };

        foreach(DefaultCountries dc in dsf.DefaultCountries) {
            var c = new Country {
                Name = dc.Name };

            sr.Countries.Add(c);
        }

        r.SubRegions.Add(sr);
   }

   rlist.Add(r);
}

DataContext dc = new DataContext();
dc.Regions.InsertAllOnSubmit(rlist);
dc.Submit();
```

This should work for you, and it is the easiest way I have found to copy data.